# rename dataframe column values based on dict and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

For a mock df:

```
tempdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'class': ['a', 'a', 'a','a','a','a', 'b','b','b','b', 'b', 'b'],
    'type': ['train', 'train', 'train','train', 'test','test', 'train','train','train','train','test','test'],
    'mag': [15,15,8,8,15,8, 2,2,6,6,6,6]
})
print(tempdf)
   class   type    mag
0      a  train     15
1      a  train     15
2      a  train      8
3      a  train      8
4      a   test     15
5      a   test      8
6      b  train      2
7      b  train      2
8      b  train      6
9      b  train      6
10     b   test      6
11     b   test      6
```

I want to rename the mag column values according to a new mag-level name, so that the different classes can be sorted according to a relative magnification level.

I want to end up with:

```
   class   type    mag
0      a  train   mag-level2
1      a  train   mag-level2
2      a  train   mag-level1
3      a  train   mag-level1
4      a   test   mag-level2
5      a   test   mag-level1
6      b  train   mag-level1
7      b  train   mag-level1
8      b  train   mag-level2
9      b  train   mag-level2
10     b   test   mag-level2
11     b   test   mag-level2
```

I defined a function to create the new names depending on how many magnification levels are present in the original data

```
def make_magnif_groups(class):
    # create magnification label based on number of magnifications for dataset
    labels = ['mag-level{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(np.unique(class))+1)]
    # assign value with mag-level
    paired = dict(zip(np.unique(sorted(class)), labels))
    return paired
```

Printing the mags for each class looks like:

```
tempmag = tempdf.groupby('class')['mag'].unique()
print(tempmag)
class
a    [15, 8]
b     [2, 6]
```

My goal is to rename the mag col values according to their respective magnification level, which i specify via:

```
for i in range(len(tempmag)):
    pairs = make_magnif_groups(tempmag[i])
```

which looks like:

```
print(pairs)
{8: 'mag-level1', 15: 'mag-level2'}
{2: 'mag-level1', 6: 'mag-level2'}
```

I was thinking that using the `tempdf.replace({'mag': pairs})` is needed. However, I can't apply the function directly because my actual df may have, for example mag of `8 = mag-level1` for one class but is a `mag-level2` for another class...

I was trying various things with `df.groupby(['species', 'type'])` (Note, while theory the mag should be the same in the train/test for a specific class, it isn't always the case. Hence needing to group by that as well)

`tempdf.groupby(['class', 'type']).agg({'mag': lambda x: make_magnif_groups(x)}).unstack()` returns the dict that should be used to replace all the values by for each class-type subgroup... but i'm missing the last step (or may not be approaching this in the right way at all...)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: To be clear, the original values in the `mag` column are **irrelevant**? Or what exactly does "rename the mag column values according to a new mag-level name, so that the different classes can be sorted according to a relative magnification level" mean? What is the **rule that tells you** what the new value should be in that column?

Comment: there's another column that stores the original `mag` values for metadata, so the values in this particular `mag` col can be replaced (i omitted all the other cols for the purposes of the mock df)

Comment: the rule is defined in the `make_magnif_groups` function. it doesn't really matter where it is coming from... but it's essentially how images were taken on a microscope (highly zoomed in, medium, or far, for example)

Comment: the actual numerical magnification level used is not important. i need to be able to sort according to the relative magnification level (which is generally the same for all classes -- ie. each class is taken at, for example, 3 magnification levels)